A3C agent (continuous action space) not being trained properly and only reach
I'm currently trying to implement A3C on InvertedPendulumSwingupBulletEnv-v0 environment. The code runs alright but the agent doesn't perform well. It does learn a little bit, but its episode reward does not exceed around 200.
So I've printed out some key variables and found that value of std is always 0.001 or 1, which are min and max values that I've clamped. (Please check the examples that I've written below)
I have two files, run.py and agent.py. To train the agent, I've ran run.py file, set n_step to 4 and multi to 1 for now. Thank you guys for your help.
run.py
import warnings
# warnings.filterwarnings("ignore")
import numpy as np
import torch.multiprocessing as mp
from torch.distributions import Normal
from collections import deque
import torch
import time
import gym
from agent import Worker, ActorCritic
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def visualize_env(agent=None):
    env = gym.make('InvertedPendulumSwingupBulletEnv-v0')
    env.seed(1)
    env.action_space.seed(1)
    env.render(mode='human')
    state = env.reset()
    total_rewards = 0

    for step in range(200):
        time.sleep(0.016)
        if agent is None:
            action = env.action_space.sample()
        else:
            action = agent.select_action(state)
        next_state, reward, done, _ = env.step(action)

        print("reward:", reward)
        total_rewards = total_rewards + reward
        if done:
            print("total reward:", total_rewards)
            total_rewards = 0
            state = env.reset()
        state = next_state

def evaluate(global_actor, global_epi, sync, finish, multi):
    start_time = time.time()
    env = gym.make('InvertedPendulumSwingupBulletEnv-v0')
    env.seed(1)
    recent_scores = deque(maxlen=20)
    mean_scores = []
    n_epi = 0

    while True:
        if global_epi.value == multi:
            state = env.reset()        
            score = 0
            done = False

            while not done:
                with torch.no_grad():
                    mu, std = global_actor.actor(torch.FloatTensor(state))
                    dist = Normal(mu, std)
                    action = dist.sample()
                    next_state, reward, done, _ = env.step(action)
                    state = next_state
                    score += reward
       
            with sync:
                sync.notify_all()

            with global_epi.get_lock():
                global_epi.value = 0

            recent_scores.append(score)
            mean_score = np.mean(recent_scores)
            mean_scores.append(mean_score)
            n_epi += 1
            print(f'[Episode {n_epi}] Avg. score: {mean_score: .2f}')

            if mean_score >= 600:
                with finish.get_lock():
                    finish.value = 1
                print("Achieved score 600!!!, Time : {:.2f}".format(time.time() - start_time))
            elif n_epi > 1000:
                with finish.get_lock():
                    finish.value = 1
                if np.max(mean_scores) >= 500:
                    print("Max episode finished! Achieved score 500!!!")
                elif np.max(mean_scores) >= 400:
                    print("Max episode finished! Achievd score 400!!!")
                else:
                    print("Max episode finished!")

            if finish.value == 1:
                with sync:
                    sync.notify_all()
                break

    plt.figure()
    plt.plot(np.arange(len(mean_scores)), mean_scores)
    plt.axhline(400, linestyle='--')
    plt.axhline(500, linestyle='--')
    plt.axhline(600, linestyle='--')
    plt.xlabel('Episode')
    plt.ylabel('Mean Score')
    plt.savefig('plot.png')
    plt.close()
    print('figure saved')  

    env.close()

def model_free_RL(n_steps, multi):
    global_actor = ActorCritic()
    global_actor.share_memory()

    global_epi = mp.Value('i', 0)
    sync = mp.Condition()
    finish = mp.Value('i', 0)

    # Multiprocessing
    processes = []

    for rank in range(multi + 1):
        if rank == 0:
            p = mp.Process(target=evaluate, args=(global_actor, global_epi, sync, finish, multi))
            p.start()

        else:
            worker = Worker(global_actor, global_epi, sync, finish, n_steps, rank)
            p = mp.Process(target=worker.train)
            p.start()
            processes.append(p)

    for p in processes:
        p.join()

    return worker

if __name__ == '__main__':
    while True:
        mp.set_start_method('spawn')
        print("1. visualize without learning")
        print("2. actor-critic training")
        print("3. visualize after learning")
        print("4. exit")
        menu = int(input("select: "))
        if menu == 1:
            visualize_env()
        elif menu == 2:
            n_steps = int(input("n_steps: "))
            multi = int(input("multi: ")) 
            torch.manual_seed(77)
            np.random.seed(1)
            agent = model_free_RL(n_steps, multi)
        elif menu == 3:
            visualize_env(agent)
        elif menu == 4:
            break
        else:
            print("wrong input!")

agent.py
import gym
import pybullet_envs
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.optim as optim
import torch.nn.functional as F
from torch.distributions import Normal
import numpy as np

ENV = gym.make("InvertedPendulumSwingupBulletEnv-v0")
OBS_DIM = ENV.observation_space.shape[0]
ACT_DIM = ENV.action_space.shape[0]
ACT_LIMIT = ENV.action_space.high[0]
ENV.close()

class NstepBuffer:
    def __init__(self):
        self.states = []
        self.actions = []
        self.rewards = []
        self.next_states = []
        self.dones = []

    def add(self, state, action, reward, next_state, done):
        self.states.append(state)
        self.actions.append(action)
        self.rewards.append(reward)
        self.next_states.append(next_state)
        self.dones.append(done)

    def sample(self):
        states = torch.FloatTensor(np.array(self.states))
        actions = torch.FloatTensor(np.array(self.actions))
        rewards = torch.FloatTensor(np.array(self.rewards))
        next_states = torch.FloatTensor(np.array(self.next_states))
        dones = torch.FloatTensor(np.array(self.dones))
        return states, actions, rewards, next_states, dones
    
    def reset(self):
        self.states = []
        self.actions = []
        self.rewards = []
        self.next_states = []
        self.dones = []


class ActorCritic(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(ActorCritic, self).__init__()
        
        self.hidden_size = 256
        
        self.actor_layer_1 = nn.Linear(OBS_DIM, self.hidden_size)
        self.actor_layer_2 = nn.Linear(self.hidden_size, self.hidden_size)
        self.actor_layer_3 = nn.Linear(self.hidden_size, self.hidden_size)
        
        self.critic_layer_1 = nn.Linear(OBS_DIM, self.hidden_size)
        self.critic_layer_2 = nn.Linear(self.hidden_size, self.hidden_size)
        self.critic_layer_3 = nn.Linear(self.hidden_size, self.hidden_size)

        self.mu_head = nn.Linear(self.hidden_size, ACT_DIM)
        self.std_head = nn.Linear(self.hidden_size, ACT_DIM)
        
        self.critic_head = nn.Linear(self.hidden_size, 1)
        
        self._initialize_weights()

    def _initialize_weights(self):
        for layer in self.children():
            if isinstance(layer, nn.Linear):
                nn.init.kaiming_normal_(layer.weight)
                nn.init.constant_(layer.bias, 0)
        
    def actor(self, states):
        x = F.tanh(self.actor_layer_1(states))
        x = F.tanh(self.actor_layer_2(x))
        x = F.tanh(self.actor_layer_3(x))
        mu = F.tanh(self.mu_head(x))
        std = F.softplus(self.std_head(x)).clamp(min=1e-2, max=1)
        return mu, std

    def critic(self, states):
        x = F.tanh(self.critic_layer_1(states))
        x = F.tanh(self.critic_layer_2(x))
        x = F.tanh(self.critic_layer_3(x))
        return self.critic_head(x)

class Worker(object):
    def __init__(self, global_actor, global_epi, sync, finish, n_step, seed):
        self.env = gym.make('InvertedPendulumSwingupBulletEnv-v0')
        self.env.seed(seed)
        self.lr = 0.001
        self.gamma = 0.99
        self.entropy_coef = 0.01
        self.critic_coef = 0.95

        self.global_actor = global_actor
        self.global_epi = global_epi
        self.sync = sync
        self.finish = finish
        self.optimizer = optim.Adam(self.global_actor.parameters(), lr=self.lr)
        
        self.n_step = n_step
        self.local_actor = ActorCritic()
        self.local_actor.load_state_dict(self.global_actor.state_dict())
        self.nstep_buffer = NstepBuffer()

    def select_action(self, state):
        state = torch.FloatTensor(state).unsqueeze(0)
        mu, std = self.local_actor.actor(state)
        dist = Normal(mu, std)
        action = dist.sample()
        action = action.clamp(-ACT_LIMIT, ACT_LIMIT).squeeze(0)
        return action.numpy()
    
    def train_network(self, states, actions, rewards, next_states, dones):
        n_step_return = rewards
        for i in range(rewards.size(0) - 2, -1, -1):
            n_step_return[i] += self.gamma * n_step_return[i + 1] * (1 - dones[i + 1])

        next_values = self.local_actor.critic(next_states[-1]).squeeze(0)
        td_targets = n_step_return + (self.gamma ** self.n_step) * next_values * (1 - dones[-1])
        
        values = self.local_actor.critic(states).squeeze(1)
        advantages = td_targets - values
        advantages = (advantages - advantages.mean()) / (advantages.std() + 1e-8)  # Normalize advantages

        critic_loss = F.mse_loss(values, td_targets.detach())

        mu, std = self.local_actor.actor(states)
        dist = Normal(mu, std)
        log_probs = dist.log_prob(actions).sum(-1)
        
        actor_loss = -(log_probs * advantages.detach()).mean()
        entropy = dist.entropy().mean()
        total_loss = actor_loss + self.critic_coef * critic_loss - self.entropy_coef * entropy
        
        print(f'values: {values}')
        print(f'td_targets: {td_targets}')
        print(f'mu: {mu}')
        print(f'std: {std}')
        print(f'advantages: {advantages}')
        print(f'log_probs: {log_probs}')
        print(f'actor_loss: {actor_loss}')
        print(f'critic_loss: {critic_loss}')
        print(f'entropy: {entropy}')
        print(f'total_loss: {total_loss}\n')

        self.optimizer.zero_grad()
        total_loss.backward()

        for global_param, local_param in zip(self.global_actor.parameters(), self.local_actor.parameters()):
                global_param._grad = local_param.grad

        self.optimizer.step()
        self.local_actor.load_state_dict(self.global_actor.state_dict())
        

    def train(self):
        step = 1

        while True:
            state = self.env.reset()
            done = False

            while not done:
                action = self.select_action(state)
                next_state, reward, done, _ = self.env.step(action)
                self.nstep_buffer.add(state, action[0], reward, next_state, done)

                if step % self.n_step == 0 or done:
                    if len(self.nstep_buffer.states) >= self.n_step:  # 필요한 transition이 충분한지 확인
                        self.train_network(*self.nstep_buffer.sample())
                    self.nstep_buffer.reset()                    
                
                state = next_state
                step += 1

            with self.global_epi.get_lock():
                self.global_epi.value += 1
            
            if self.finish.value == 1:
                break

            with self.sync:
                self.sync.wait()

        self.env.close()

I've tried to train the agent, but episode reward remains around 200 and doesn't increase anymore. Below is part of output for some key variables.
values: tensor([106.6193, 106.6194, 106.6208, 107.9898], grad_fn=<SqueezeBackward1>)                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
td_targets: tensor([100.9543, 101.6775, 102.3820, 103.0679], grad_fn=<AddBackward0>)                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
mu: tensor([[1.],                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
        [1.],                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
        [1.],                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
        [1.]], grad_fn=<TanhBackward0>)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
std: tensor([[0.0100],                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
        [0.0100],                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
        [0.0100],                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
        [0.0100]], grad_fn=<ClampBackward1>)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
advantages: tensor([-1.2416e+00,  3.6024e-05,  1.2072e+00,  3.4318e-02],                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
       grad_fn=<DivBackward0>)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
log_probs: tensor([11.6170, 11.6170, 11.6170, 11.6170], grad_fn=<SumBackward1>)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
actor_loss: 8.940696716308594e-08                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
critic_loss: 24.676780700683594                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
entropy: -3.1862316131591797                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
total_loss: 23.474803924560547                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
values: tensor([108.0976, 100.0598,  88.0920,  80.1200], grad_fn=<SqueezeBackward1>)                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
td_targets: tensor([75.9576, 76.5834, 77.1923, 77.7855], grad_fn=<AddBackward0>)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
mu: tensor([[ 1.],                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
        [ 1.],                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
        [ 1.],                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
        [-1.]], grad_fn=<TanhBackward0>)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
std: tensor([[0.0100],                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
        [0.0100],                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
        [0.0100],                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
        [1.0000]], grad_fn=<ClampBackward1>)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
advantages: tensor([-1.1303, -0.4743,  0.4780,  1.1265], grad_fn=<DivBackward0>)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
log_probs: tensor([-418.2179, -418.2179, -418.2179,  -11.1293], grad_fn=<SumBackward1>)                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
actor_loss: -114.65037536621094                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
critic_loss: 427.0928039550781                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
entropy: -2.0349390506744385                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
total_loss: 291.1081237792969                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
values: tensor([81.7005, 67.2010, 46.0492, 37.3842], grad_fn=<SqueezeBackward1>)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
td_targets: tensor([-3.5973, -3.0507, -2.5099, -1.9719], grad_fn=<AddBackward0>)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
mu: tensor([[-1.],                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
        [-1.],                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
        [-1.],                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
        [-1.]], grad_fn=<TanhBackward0>)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
std: tensor([[1.],                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
        [1.],                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
        [1.],                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
        [1.]], grad_fn=<ClampBackward1>)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
advantages: tensor([-1.1740, -0.4510,  0.5914,  1.0337], grad_fn=<DivBackward0>)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
log_probs: tensor([-6.5776, -6.5776, -6.5776, -6.5776], grad_fn=<SumBackward1>)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
actor_loss: 7.152557373046875e-07                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
critic_loss: 4029.479248046875                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
entropy: 1.4189385175704956                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
total_loss: 3827.990966796875                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
                                                                                                                


